# OpenGL multiple viewports with 3d-2d viewing

Tags: opengl, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to draw two viewports, the one on top having a 3D stuff into it, and the other at bottom with a 2D stuff fed into it. However, whatever 2D stuff i draw in the bottom viewport is not rendered to the screen. Below is the piece of my code.

```
    void display() {

    //first viewport of height h/8
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height / 8);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    /*glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();*/
    gluOrtho2D(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glRectf(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glFlush();

    //second viewport of height 7h/8
    glViewport(0, 2*height / 8, width, 7 * (height / 8));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    aspect = (double)8 * width / ((double)height * 7);
    gluPerspective(fieldofview, aspect, nearPlane, farPlane);
    // setup viewing matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 20.0f, 10.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    draw_model(objs[0]); // draw the plane
    draw_model(objs[1]); // draw the first diamond
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(moving_position.x, moving_position.y, moving_position.z);
    draw_model(objs[2]); // draw the second diamond
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    move(8);
    // set up menus
}

void reshape(int x, int y) {
    width = x;
    height = y;
    if (height == 0)        // not divided by zero
        height = 1;
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(position_x, position_y);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    winId = glutCreateWindow("Mesh Viewer");
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);       // display function
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Below is my output, with no rectangle in 1st viewport:
[image]

Moreover, can I apply some background color to the second viewport without using the `glScissor`?

Comment: For the love of all that's holy, people, stop using the fixed function crap. It's been deprecated for... Well, a really long time. I'm not saying you have to switch to Vulkan insanity, but at least go with 4.3 core.

Comment: haha.. i am helpless about this. i know it is deprecated, but the professor of my course wants me to build project on it. can't help. he is outdated

Comment: We still do that for some introductory courses (I'm a lecturer)  but my last GL class started with shaders and core 4.3. (Most of my students have Macs.) Anything beyond 1st semester with fixed function is irresponsible on the part of university and a disservice to the students. PLEASE quote me on that.

Comment: i am not sure if i can go to my prof and tell him that he is teaching obsolete stuff :P

Comment: @DavidLively IMO the fixed function pipeline is very helpful for learning basic 3D concepts (and some OpenGL concepts, like viewports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` was causing the problem. Removing the second occurence for it resolved the problem.